# Асинхронный режим PostgreSQL. Логика работы функции pqFlush

Tags: c, postgresql, асинхронность

В своем приложении я создаю несколько подключений к БД и в каждом из них отправляю буфер данных на сервер, а затем по таймеру пытаюсь сбросить буферы на сервер.
Сброс буфером осуществляю с помощью функции PQFlush.
Суть в том, что чем реже я вызываю PQFlush, тем дольше отправляются данные. То есть, если я вызываю ее по таймеру раз в 100 мс, то данные сбрасываются довольно быстро. Если же установить таймер например на 1 с, то данные будут сбрасываться чуть ли не минуту, а то и больше. В чем логика происходящего?